# How delphi rsa PKCS#1 v1.5

Tags: python, delphi, cryptography, rsa

I did research but I couldn't find an understandable source.

Python code like this.

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15


class PycryptodomeAuthSigner(protocol.AuthSigner):

    def __init__(self, rsa_key_path=None):
        super(PycryptodomeAuthSigner, self).__init__()

        if rsa_key_path:
            with open(rsa_key_path + '.pub', 'rb') as rsa_pub_file:
                self.public_key = rsa_pub_file.read()
                print self.public_key;
            with open(rsa_key_path, 'rb') as rsa_priv_file:
                self.rsa_key = RSA.import_key(rsa_priv_file.read())

    def Sign(self, data):
        h = SHA256.new(data)
        return pkcs1_15.new(self.rsa_key).sign(h)

    def GetPublicKey(self):
        return self.public_key
```

I found such a resource but it wants module from me (512 bytes long). I have no idea how the module is calculated.

```
uses

  System.SysUtils, RSAObj, MiscObj;

var 
  RSA: TRSAEncSign;

begin  
  try   
    RSA := TRSAEncSign.Create;
    RSA.keyLength := kl2048;
    RSA.encType := oaep;
    RSA.outputFormat := base64;
    RSA.modulus :=       'nHOjA+WQ8NgRJ1O2ZvbQE7h3RaxBNGCxwwudVvGcqjE4+bmhO9hE/2iX/uZEhTNDEEVS6OSm3aO/jEpjJ3iu+baZq16Zd3leAgNmvISlREbu25OaMA1sN/an9Hkrda5es9xcnRoCvPfv76'

      + 'WXFSaaag+mIE9vlZG7InR9kOdESNHXvaFkhAOW7lPquVv/jwsCtP/jXSOvRWSXjvSFJvoiP1i1MKd4imFg/TUk8LRQ1onehiyMs1719AH5rOjPr/lasTB0Do8Zc3NwEkj2+W2ylMZYH5KvQ1YkF6bc6sg40nq4hWgyZ3a9MmacPP3u4m9nbyO8WCPpcYY3uXwDn6tl4Q==';
    RSA.PublicExponent := 'AQAB';
    WriteLn('Modulus: ' + RSA.modulus);
    WriteLn('Public Exponent: ' + RSA.PublicExponent);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18031/how-to-find-modulus-from-a-rsa-public-key

Comment: I saw that subject, but he is doing the wrong calculation.

Comment: Provide a link to the documentation for `TRSAEncSign`.

Comment: Why not using open SSL?

Comment: I do not want to use programs externally, I catch errors better in my own program.

Comment: I examined that document but I did not get any results. I have a private and pem key file, but it doesn't write modulus in them.

Comment: @MesutKaanYÖRÜK As it stands this isn't a very good question. You can improve it by asking explicitly how to use the given key types in Python within Delphi. Currently it looks like you are posting two different code fragments and ask us to make them compatible. That's however *your task*, not ours. Note that OAEP padding is not PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have to have resources to be more descriptive, but I do not have any resources so I could not write above. I am aware of the protocol but I can't write so I wrote here